# Check if file exist in multiple domains

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if a file exist in multiple domains/servers and then show the download link to the user or write an error message. I have this script working for 1 domain:

```
<?php
  $domain0='www.example.com';
  $file=$_GET['file']
  $resourceUrl = 'http://$domain0/$file';
  $resourceExists = false;

  $ch = curl_init($resourceUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_exec($ch);
  $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);

  //200 = OK
  if ($statusCode == '200') {
    $resourceExists = true;
  }

  if ($resourceExists == true) {
      echo "Exist! $file";
  } else {
      echo "$file doesnt exist!";
  }
?>
```

Now I need to check if that file exist in 4 domains, how can I do this? I don't know how to use arrays, so maybe if someone explain me ho to do this, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would create an array for domains
2. I would loop through the array with "foreach"
3. I would call a function to get the result

   ```
   function checkFileOnDomain($file,$domain) {
       $resourceUrl = "http://$domain/$file";

       $ch = curl_init($resourceUrl);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
       curl_exec($ch);
       $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);

       if($statusCode == '200') 
           return true;
   }

   $file=$_GET["file"];
   // $_GET should be sanitized!

   $domain_list=array("www.test1.com","www.test2.com"); 


   foreach ($domain_list as $domain) {
       echo "Check DOMAIN: $domain <hr/>";

       if (checkFileOnDomain($file,$domain)) {
           echo ">> [ $file ] EXISTS";
       } else {
           echo ">> [ $file ] DOES NOT EXIST";
       }
       echo "<br/><br/>";
   } unset($domain);
   ```

EDIT:

To apply your specifications, you need an extra variable before foreach.

```
    $link_to_file="";
    foreach ($domain_list as $domain) {

        if (checkFileOnDomain($file,$domain)) {
            $link_to_file="$domain/$file";
            break; // get first result and quit
        }

    } unset($domain);

    if (!empty($link_to_file)) {
            echo $link_to_file; //file is here
    } else {
            echo "404";
    }
```

Comment: i think this is the cleanest solution, i'll try it when i have some time

Comment: ok, i tried but i got stick on one problem: foreach passes all the domains and then gives me the results, but i don't need all the results, i need this results: if the file exist on one of the domains inside the array, it shows only the link to that domain and nothing else; if the file does not exist in anyone of the domains inside the array, then it echo a text "404 file not found" and nothing else. is this possible?

Comment: great! sorry for late answer, but i was ill, anyway the code works great! thank you very much.  Still i have a question, is possible to "cache" the results to html, because i am on shared hosting, and 50-70k users doing the "foreach" 140k times or more cause heavy load to cpu, so i want to convert the result to html page, and maybe let the cache expire every 6h or something like this

Comment: ps: all my links that have the code above are like this: `http://www.example.com/dl.php?file=filefolder/filename.mp4`

Comment: @eazy You should look here for your answer. It shows that you can either create a page with the results, or create a file with a stored variable of your results: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746138/the-most-simple-way-to-cache-mysql-query-results-using-php)

Comment: @easy You could also look here for 3 different methods to cache the results: [outside link](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/34972/14863/cache-a-large-array-json-serialize-or-var_export.html)

Answer (score 0):

An array should solve the problem for you. This creates an array of the domains you want to check, and then cycles through them one by one running the code you wrote.

If you're struggling with arrays, have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) for some more information

```
<?php

    // Create an array of domains
    $domains = ['www.example.com', 'www.example2.com', ...];

    // Cycle through all the domains and run the code
    foreach($domains as $domain) {

        $domain0='www.example.com';
        $file=$_GET['file']
        $resourceUrl = 'http://$domain0/$file';
        $resourceExists = false;

        $ch = curl_init($resourceUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        //200 = OK
        if($statusCode == '200') { 
            $resourceExists = true; 
        } else if($resourceExists == false) {

        }

        if ($resourceExists == true) {
            echo "Exist! $file";
        } else {
            echo "$file doesnt exist!";
        }

    }

?>
```