# How persist a simple variable for all different sessions in php?

Tags: php, session, variables, caching

There is a very complex calculation and system health verifications that returns a numeric variable.

This variable will be displayed in every page, But I don't want to make this verification and calculation every navigation. This value should be visible to EVERY session for all users, not just one session. the most simple solution could be a global variable that would persist and be available for all sessions.

Filesytem or database are not an option.

Is that possible in PHP?

Comment: Cache the query result then.

Comment: the question is exactaly how to cache the query.

Comment: Then it's duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746138/the-most-simple-way-to-cache-mysql-query-results-using-php

Comment: it is not an SQL query, i edited the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Well it's the same, cache the result the same way you would cache a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php) could be a solution.